# Proof check: Divided difference is exactly the coefficient of the interpolation polynomial (in Newton basis)

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification

Below is my proof, which utilizes showing that the coefficient satisfies the recursive definition of the divided difference.

Anyone can verify if anything is unjustified/wrong in the proof?

I'm asking because I'm quite confused of the last part of my proof.

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific in what points cause your confusion. // You could be more forceful in distancing the $g$ coefficients from being defined as divided differences, perhaps use another type of braces. You could also state the sub-claims about the argument symmetry and the recursive property first before proving them. Depending on what level you are at, you might also need to state the induction claim for the equality of $g$ coefficients and $f$ divided differences more distinctly.

Comment: My main confusion is in the third last and second last paragraph. In third last paragraph I said $g[x_1,...,x_n] = g[x_n,...,x_1]$ and I am pretty sure that is because $Lf_{n-2}^{(2)}(x)$ is also an interpolant so we can apply the same proof I did above to it. For the second last paragraph, it is the same idea as the third last paragraph, except I apply the theorem finitely many times. The annoying part I can't seem to word properly is that each divided difference splits into not 1 but 2 smaller divided differences, so I cannot write anything more meaningful than this...

Comment: Yes, that is a common problem with on-the-fly induction statements. If you are uncomfortable with that, separate the parts out. Show that this argument symmetry follows from comparing the leading monomial coefficients, which is then true for all point sequences. Then show the recursion equation by comparing the two leading monomial coefficients using the argument symmetry. You need to explicitly justify that $Lf^{(i)}_{n-1}$ has coefficients identical to the ones of $L^{(i)}_n$. This is clear from the construction, but not given just from the interpolation property.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "argument symmetry" and "point sequence" in the phrase "Show that this argument symmetry follows from comparing the leading monomial coefficients, which is then true for all point sequences. Then show the recursion equation by comparing the two leading monomial coefficients using the argument symmetry."? Thank you!

Comment: I've also updated my solution to include more detail, do you mind to check if that needs more clarification anywhere?

Comment: I was just giving a name to $g[x_1,..,x_n]=g[x_n,..,x_n]$, invariance under a symmetry of the argument sequence. The argument is a finite sequence of points. And yes, for my impression the arguments flow better in the new version. If you have the time, let some time pass and then compare the two versions if you missed some twist of language from the first version that would be nice to also have in the new one. But that's only an impression, I could not say concretely where that would apply.